# how to embed an .AVI in html?

Tags: html, avi

I've found some examples of .AVI in html on the web.
But my page  http://pianocheater.com/VIDEO.html is problematic.

It's fine with chrome on my pc.
In IE, you get that dang bar at the top and then the videos are blank after that.
It works on my pc, but not others' so I figured it'd be codecs or something??

Here's the existing html...  (sorry, note sure how to get pretty html in here)

```
<object width=288 height=512
  id      ="MediaPlayer"
  type    ="application/x-oleobject"
  standby ="Loading Windows Media Player components..."
  classid ="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
  codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/
            en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">
  <param name="showControls" value="true">
  <param name="autoStart"    value="false">
  <param name="filename"     value="img/adg.avi">
  <embed width=288 height=512  src="img/adg.avi"
         type="application/x-mplayer2" showControls=1 autoStart=0></embed>
 </object>
```

I know that .AVI will keep mac people from seeing em.
That's ok.  My midi app doesn't have a mac version.
I also know that .AVIs don't stream well.
When I convert to .MOV or .WMV the audio lags terribly.
(And this is a midi app - sound is important.)

Any tips or ideas would be most appreciated :)

Comment: What stops Mac users from seeing videos in AVI containers?

Comment: I just read that somewhere.  I thought quicktime was the default on a mac and it can't do .AVI?  I could very likely be wrong about that...

Comment: My copy of Quicktime is perfectly capable of dealing with video in an AVI container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done a lot easier in flash.

Convert the video to FLV and use the open source [JW](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) player to play it.  You can convert the video using the open source [ffmpeg](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg). (There are a lot of free GUI front-ends to ffmpeg)

Comment: So ffmpeg will convert .AVI to .FLV with no audio lag?
And this JW is a .FLV player I can embed in html or somethin?
Well, I'll start googlin'...

Comment: I found the "Video4Web Converter" - it may just be a gui on ffmpeg, too.  But it's pretty dang easy.
And the .FLV audio doesn't lag :)

Still fighting with JW to get the dang video to display.
That's probably just somethin' I'm doing wrong though.

Thanks for your help!

I can't believe it's so painful to put up a dang video in html :o

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure the route I took was the optimal one...
But for future reference:

bought "BSR Screen Recorder 4" to capture my app in an .AVI
got (free) Moyea "Video4Web Converter" to convert AVI to FLV
(a little lag, during the recording and converting processes, but not too bad)
got (free) [http://flv-player.net/players/maxi/
(which is a .swf that you embed in html that plays the .flv)
resulting in:
[http://pianocheater.com/VIDEO.html]

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just using  by itself?

```
<embed src="img/adg.avi"/>
```

…but you might be better off just using YouTube or something similar.

Comment: Seems to work fine for my firefox under ubuntu, but I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: On my Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m it requires a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just to update the answer and help someone, html has a video tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

More on:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)