# playing video file on asp.net working fine with IE but not chrome and firefox

Tags: video, cross-browser

I enclosed this code snippet:

```
<embed AutoSize="false" DisplaySize="0" EnableContextMenu="0" name="RAOCXplayer" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="1" src="video.avi" width="250"></embed>
```

into an ASP.NET webpage.

- It works fine with IE8,9
- When I open it with Firefox and Chrome they both display "missing plugin". Which plugin should I install in order to play the embedded avi file on asp.net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to embed an .AVI in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840355/how-to-embed-an-avi-in-html)

Comment: I am asking also which plugins to play with the avi file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following articles/posts around the 'net. They all have pros and cons, so pick the ones that work in your environment for your specific needs best:

- [W3Schools.com - Playing Videos in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp)
- [Embedding .avi files in a web page](https://www.msu.edu/~kellerj/test/embed.htm)
- [StackOverflow - how to embed an .AVI in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840355/2291)