# Way to show AVI uploaded video on webpage

Tags: php, html

I'm trying my first CodeIgniter E-learning project that a teacher can upload their video file, and show it on lesson page.

The problem I was thinking about is if our customer has AVI video files and wants to upload them and show them on webpage, but most browsers do not support an AVI file fromat.

So how can I solve this problem?

I tried videojs but it doesn't work, Is there any suggestion? 
I'm thinking about 2 options

- Is there any plugin/software that can display AVI video and embed it on webpage?
- Create convert process to convert AVI to MP4 => I think it will more complicated.

> I found another option to do that: Use Google Drive API to upload and generate preview link to show. It worked!! 
>  If you guys have another effective way please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

1. I think for embedding avi video. That is previously answered in [how to embed an .AVI in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840355/how-to-embed-an-avi-in-html)
2. As for converting video. I think you can use something like ffmpeg or avconv for converting video in the backend to convert it first and then embed it or do it in Flash or in html video tag

Comment: Thanks for your advice <br/> 1. In your link have an old plugin that most of browsers don't support anymore <br/> 2. I will try it out! :D